# How do I keep data in my Deque in Android Studio on Buttonclick?

Tags: android

I am trying to save data to a Deque on buttonclick and display the data in a tablelayout. My issue is that every time I trigger the onclick, the Deque loses all previous data. I tried to instantiate the Deque outside the onCreate method and it did not work. I am using a Deque as a stack because I need to display the data LIFO. Any help on this would be very much appreciated. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonAdd;
    private EditText editText1;
    private Deque<String> input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);
        final Deque<String> input = new ArrayDeque<String>();

        buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

                String data = editText1.getText().toString();
                input.addFirst(data);

                Deque<String> inputData = input;

                while (!inputData.isEmpty()) {

                    String s = inputData.removeFirst();
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);

                    TextView textViewData = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    textViewData.setText(s);
                    textViewData.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    row.addView(textViewData);

                    table.addView(row);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the previous data on Application start ?

Comment: No, just during the app session

Comment: `Deque<String> inputData = input;` This doesn't _copy_ a new deque. It's the very same one.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
String s = inputData.removeFirst();
```

With this operation, you remove (delete) the next entry and since you do it in a loop:

```
while (!inputData.isEmpty()) {
```

it simply empties the queue.

What you want is to iterate over the queue without removing anything:

```
for (String element : inputData) {
     textViewData.setText(s);
}
```